# EKS Pod with Multiple IAM Roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-eks

Is it possible for a pod to assume multiple IAM roles?
Its definitely possible to dynamically switch the env variable AWS_ROLE_ARN value.
But do we have a straight approach to support multiple at a time?

like,

```
AWS_ROLE_ARN: test
AWS_ROLE_ARN2: test-2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read in the documentation, IAM roles for pods are working like instance profile for EC2. So you can't use easily 2 roles at the same time.

Source : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/iam-roles-for-service-accounts.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the right documentation.

Answer (score 3):

You can't assign two Roles to your Pod.  However, your Pod can assume different Roles if it needs to change its permissions at run-time.

For instance:

1. Create two Roles, `ProducerRole` and `ConsumerRole`, with appropriate permissions and the following trust policy:

   ```
   {
     "Version": "2012-10-17",
     "Statement": [
       {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Principal": {
           "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:role/PodRole"
         },
         "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
       }
     ]
   }
   ```
2. Create a third Role, `PodRole`, with the following permission policy:

   ```
   {
     "Version": "2012-10-17",
     "Statement": [
       {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": [
           "sts:AssumeRole"
         ],
         "Resource": [
           "arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:role/ProducerRole",
           "arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:role/ConsumerRole"
         ]
       }
     ]
   }
   ```

   and the following trust policy:

   ```
   {
     "Version": "2012-10-17",
     "Statement": [
       {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Principal": {
           "Service": "eks.amazonaws.com"
         },
         "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
       }
     ]
   }
   ```

   Also give this role whatever other basic permissions its needs to be your Pod role.
3. Configure your EKS Pod to use `PodRole`.
4. Inside your EKS Pod, assume either `ProducerRole` or `ConsumerRole`, depending on which set of permissions you need at the time.